# Seeking location of all Universities and Colleges in North America?

Tags: data, united-states

This seems fairly straightforward but I'm having trouble finding the right data. All I need is the name, address, and lat long of all universities and colleges in North America.

I've come across a list of many universities in America here: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/578065.html but just by name.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about GIS.

Comment: Check out this link    http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f8cf498555344ef880aa3361239c5abb

Comment: Discuss closure of this question here: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/are-questions-about-obtaining-xy-data-on-topic

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you pull the data from the [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) database.  I will tell you that I went through a similar process a few years ago and it is anything but clean.  However, you can get a large number of points that you are looking for.

You'll want to look in the the following attributes to get started:

- fclass = 'P' (Places) or 'S' (School)
- fcode = 'PPL', 'PPLA', 'PPLA2', 'SCH', 'SCHM', 'BLDG', 'UNIV'

I loaded the data all into a [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) database and then you can query the data or add a geometry column to turn it into spatial features.

Answer (score 4):

The **National Center for Education Statistics** has a database of colleges in the USA.  This [link](https://nces.ed.gov/globallocator/) provides addresses for colleges, which you could geocode to get coordinates.

**Maponics** provides College Campus boundaries and points for over 2,100 colleges in the USA and Canada.  Some details at [this link](http://www.maponics.com/social-places).

[image: CCNY-Columbia]

Answer (score 2):

I found this when I was looking for shapefiles about universities allover the world
https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/4f4e4acee4b07f02db67fb39